# Unable to append string

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I can't figure out why the output of `self.tmp` is null.

Here is the code I use

```
[self.dict enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop)
{
    NSMutableString *t = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@", key, obj];
    [self.tmp appendString:t];
}];

NSLog(@"%@", self.tmp) --> print null;
```

`tmp` is declared as `NSMutableString`.

I can confirm that `dict` ivar contain data.

Comment: Where and how is `self.temp` initialized?

Comment: What's the initial value of `self.tmp`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `self.tmp` is itself `nil`. You declared it, but do you ever set it or allocate it initially? The append will only work if the thing you're appending to is an existing string.

In Objective-C, you won't see an error if you try the append to a `nil` object, you'll only see the result you're seeing, which is that nothing happened.

Just before the code you post here, you might want to do this:

```
self.tmp = [NSMutableString string];
```

Comment: In the scenario described above which is the best approach to build single string based on dictionary data ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have your ivar tmp initialized and allocated, be sure to initialize it as `@""`, that's the only problem why you could be having problems. You don't need to explicitly allocate it, you can use an autoreleased object calling some of the class' methods:

```
self.temp=[NSMutableString stringWithString:@""];
```

If your string is set as nil, you are adding something to nil, and since nil can't handle that behavior you get this unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm that `self.tmp != nil` before you start?

Comment: @foho: As others have posted in more detail ithan me, that is the cause of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

self.tmp isn't created.
Do:

`self.tmp = [NSMutableString new];`